# best way to round string

Tags: java, android

What is the best way to round the price to 2 decimal places in the same in command.
example: 7.254545 to 7.25
In case that the data appear as string ?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsHashMapList;
holder._price.setText(productsHashMapList.get(position).get("price"));
```

1. Using split ? so split after 2 numbers after ( . ) ?
2. Using ( .format("%.2f", d) ) .
3. Using xml TextView ( IF POSSIBLE ) ?

why? and please give me some info because the second way not work and this message appear : 
 java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Comment: Which message??

Comment: sorry : 
 java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Comment: Is `d` a String? If so, you'll need to convert it to `double` first.

Comment: Use `double d = Double.parseDouble(str)` to convert string to double first then use `String rounded = String.format("%.2f",d)` to round the double to 2 dp in a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: @RickyMo Thx. This work , but which one is prefer ? this ? or Using split ? so split after 2 numbers after ( . ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your string to double using

```
Double yourNumber = Double.parseDouble(yournumberinstring);
```

Then to restrict it to 2 decimal places use

```
String.format("%.2f", yourNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go (this will round the number):

```
double val = Double.parseDouble(productsHashMapList.get(position).get("price"));
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(val);
bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
holder._price.setText(""+bd.floatValue());
```

Comment: Why is that preferable to another method?

Comment: Why not directly initialize `BigDecimal` object by calling the String constructor? `new BigDecimal("7.254545");`

Comment: It is preferrable because the closest one is solution 2 but that does not round numbers. That will just "cut" anything beyond 2 decimal points

Comment: The official document of Big Decimal says "Note: For values other than float and double NaN and ±Infinity, this constructor is compatible with the values returned by Float.toString(float) and Double.toString(double). This is generally the preferred way to convert a float or double into a BigDecimal, as it doesn't suffer from the unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor"